# Ajax not reloading the table when entry is deleted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I have the following button in my view

```
<button onclick="delete_article(<?php echo $property['ID']?>)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

that corresponds to this function in my codeingter controller

```
function delete($id)
{
    $this->News_m->delete($id);
    echo json_encode(data);
}
```

Here is my model code if need:

```
function delete($id){
    $this->db->where('ID', $id);
    $this->db->delete('news');
}
```

I am new to AJAX and would like to know how i would code the ajax function for this i currently have the following but it is not working! Could someone please give me a hand here.

This is what I have in my script.js file at the moment

```
function delete_article(id){
    // ajax delete data in database
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/eaglefruit/news/delete" + id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE:

The code is working for the delete part but the table in the backend does not update itself until i refresh the page how do I make the reload occur with Ajax?

Comment: Is `data` in your delete function a global constant?

Comment: shot in the dark... `delete" + id` ... missing slash between delete and id?

Comment: no it is not a global constant

Comment: The tables data is not retrieved with ajax is that the problem?

Comment: Then what is it, a variable needs the dollar sign in PHP and where does it comes from? Can't see it in your code.

Comment: So in all theory I can remove the success: function(data)?

Comment: please show relationship of button to row in the html. You need to validate a response from server and use ajax success to remove row

Comment: I mean the delete in your controller. The success function of the ajax is where you update the table.

Comment: So after the delete has occurred why how do I reload my table?

Comment: Simplest is just remove the row after verifying the delete response is successful

Comment: how would i do that @charlietfl

Comment: Have model return boolean to controller, then send that as response in ajax. Confirm boolean in ajax success and then remove row in browser. Need html relationship to be known to help more. Alternative is return new table html and replace existing but that is extra server load for no real good reason

Comment: The `data` in the `function(data)` is the respond from the server. How you reload your table, with the information you provided nobody can tell for sure. And looking at your code `echo json_encode(data)` wont produce anything but error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh the page if you are using Ajax. Instead of refreshing, You can remove the exact row which is being deleted. If you try to refresh the page, there is no use of using Ajax and you can simply make a post or get request which will reload the page automatically

try something like this

```
<tr id='row<?php echo $property['ID']; ?>'>.........</tr>
```

---

```
function delete_article(id){
    // ajax delete data in database
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/eaglefruit/news/delete" + id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
              $("#row"+id).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: selector syntax is broken. Also requires that html has same ID format

Comment: Yes (@charlietfl), The row has to be marked with exact format.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following

Set up the flag to be return from AJAX, "0" or "1" for example. I know that for Java Servlets would be, you would have to check for PHP(sorry):

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(//1 or 0 in case everything went according to plan);
```

Here is the tricky part....

Assign an id to every tr, for example:

```
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr id="00001">
       <td>0001</td>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="00002">
       <td>0002</td>
       <td>Jane</td>
       <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="00003">
       <td>0003</td>
       <td>Baby</td>
       <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In your AJAX request in the response success method validate your "data" variable such as:

```
if(data=="1"){
   $(#id).remove();
   //Where id I´m hopping is the same ID from **delete_article(id)**
}else{
  alert("Something is wrong");
}
```

Remeber that in order for this to work you have to add JQuery

Good luck:

:)